# Connection between derivability and invertibility of a function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In my lecture notes it says that if $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in H \subset\mathbb{R}$, then $f(x)$ is invertible. This specific question raises a more general question: How is the invertibility  of a function linked to the derivative (if it exists)?

Comment: There is the so-called Inverse Function Theorem that says if the derivative of a function is nondegenerate (not 0 basically), then it has an inverse locally. However if a function is invertible, the derivative need not to be non zero (for example, $f(x) = x^3$).

Comment: You probably mean *derivability* (for differentiability) ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Yes, thank you! Edit done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ differentiable.

What is for sure:

1. If $f^\prime$ is positive or negative then $f$ is a bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $f[\mathbb R]$ as $f$ is monotonous and continuous.
2. If $f^\prime$ vanishes, $f$ can still be invertible. Example $f: x \mapsto x^3$ with $f^\prime(0) = 0$.
3. If $f^\prime$ vanishes at a point $x_0$ and has a minimim or maximum at that point, then $f$ isn't invertible.
4. $f$ can be invertible while $f^\prime(x_n) = 0$ where $\{x_n\}$ is a converging sequence.

Answer (score 2):

A continuous function on an interval of real numbers is invertible if and only if it is strictly monotone. (This is a good exercise!) And a differentiable function on an interval is strictly monotone if and only if its derivative is always positive or always negative.

Comment: thank you for your help! I would like to choose both questions as the answer but can only choose one...